# addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath before commit to app store

Tags: ios

Should I mark my coreData file `"skip backUp Attribute"` in my project before I commit my app to App Store?
And if I don't want to backup any files,which folders I must to skip?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., should be backed up by iCloud.

Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location when the user exits the app.

StackOverflow Reference :
[iOS: Do not back up attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239147/ios-do-not-back-up-attribute)

> My app has a number of files that need to be stored on the device
>   permanently for my app to function properly offline. However, those
>   files do not contain user data and don't need to be backed up. How can
>   I prevent them from being backed up?

On iOS, apps are responsible for ensuring that only user data and not application data is backed up to iCloud and iTunes. The exact steps necessary vary between iOS version, so this QA will describe the process for each version of iOS. For more information on exactly what data should or should not be backed up.

More References :

[How do I prevent files from being backed up?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html)

[Performance Tips](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW17)

[iOS - Flag entire Document directory as do not backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964831/ios-flag-entire-document-directory-as-do-not-backup)